# Rich Card attachments are not showing on web chat or Skype

Tags: botframework

Rich Card attachments are not showing on web chat or Skype, but showing fine on the emulator. The attachment contains the correct data and attributes and works fine if I use ContentType + ContentURL. But if I use rich card attachments, they don't show up on Web Chat or Skype. This is my code. Please help.

```
Message reply = context.MakeMessage();
var actions = new List<Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Action>();
actions.Add(new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Action
{
    Title = $"I like it",
    Message = $"I like it message"
});
actions.Add(new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Action
{
    Title = $"Show me more",
    Message = $"Show me more message"
});
reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
reply.Attachments.Add(new Attachment()
{

    Title = p.Title,
    TitleLink = p.DetailPageURL,
    ThumbnailUrl = p.MediumImage,
    Text = p.Title,
    Actions = actions,
    FallbackText ="The message attachment is not rendering for: " + p.Title

});            
await context.PostAsync(reply);
context.Wait(MessageReceived);
```

Comment: Looks like it's working on Skype for Mac now. Version 7.31

Answer (score 0):

From the bot framework page:

> Important:You should test Skype bots using the developer version of the Skype Web App until updated Skype apps for desktop and mobile are available at the end of July. https://web.skype.com/en/?ecsoverride=developer

Answer (score 0):

This should be resolved now with latest Skype clients now that Bot Framework V3 has been released.